# Android Unexpectedly app has stopped

Tags: android, android-emulator

My Android app is getting crashed while I was going to this particular page. I have added the activity in android manifesto also. Here is my java code.

I have 6-7 screens Menu to all other screens. I am also passing the the logcat file

```
package com.innernet.airway;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

    public class measure extends Activity implements OnSeekBarChangeListener {
         Button ok,logout, cancel;
         TextView p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7;

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.measure);
        ok = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ok);
        p1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.percentage);
        p2= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.percentage2);
        p3= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.percentage3);
        p4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.percentage4);
        p5 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.percentage5);
        p6 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.percentage6);
        p7 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.percentage7);


        SeekBar sb = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        sb.setMax(100);
        sb.setProgress(50);
        sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        SeekBar sb2 = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar2);
        sb2.setMax(100);
        sb2.setProgress(50);
        sb2.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        SeekBar sb3 = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar3);
        sb3.setMax(100);
        sb3.setProgress(50);
        sb3.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        SeekBar sb4 = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar4);
        sb4.setMax(100);
        sb4.setProgress(50);
        sb4.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        SeekBar sb5 = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar5);
        sb5.setMax(100);
        sb5.setProgress(50);
        sb5.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        SeekBar sb6 = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar6);
        sb6.setMax(100);
        sb6.setProgress(50);
        sb6.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        SeekBar sb7 = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar7);
        sb7.setMax(100);
        sb7.setProgress(50);
        sb7.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);


        ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Datastored successully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


        });

        logout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                        "logout successully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


        });

        cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(measure.this, measure.class));
            }


        });

        }
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar v, int progress, boolean isUser) {


            switch (v.getId())
            {

            case R.id.seekBar1:

                p1.setText(Integer.toString(progress)+"%") ;
                break;

            case R.id.seekBar2:

                p2.setText(Integer.toString(progress)+"%");
                break;


            case R.id.seekBar3:

                p3.setText(Integer.toString(progress)+"%");
                break;


            case R.id.seekBar4:

                p4.setText(Integer.toString(progress)+"%");
                break;

            case R.id.seekBar5:

                p5.setText(Integer.toString(progress)+"%");
                break;

            case R.id.seekBar6:

                p6.setText(Integer.toString(progress)+"%");
                break;
         case R.id.seekBar7:

                p7.setText(Integer.toString(progress)+"%");
                break;
            }
                }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    }
```

Error Log :

```
06-18 13:43:43.864: E/Trace(628): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-18 13:43:44.314: D/dalvikvm(628): GC_CONCURRENT freed 77K, 2% free 11143K/11271K, paused 37ms+8ms, total 98ms
06-18 13:43:44.314: D/dalvikvm(628): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 36ms
06-18 13:43:44.423: D/android.widget.GridLayout(628): vertical constraints: y5-y0>=1038, y1-y0>=128, y2-y1>=128, y4-y3>=128, y5-y4>=128, y5-y0<=1038, y5-y4<=30, y4-y3<=30, y2-y1<=30, y1-y0<=40 are inconsistent; permanently removing: y5-y0<=1038, y5-y4<=30, y4-y3<=30, y2-y1<=30, y1-y0<=40. 
06-18 13:43:44.436: D/android.widget.GridLayout(628): horizontal constraints: x1-x0>=144, x2-x1>=144, x3-x2>=0, x4-x3>=144, x5-x4>=0, x6-x5>=188, x4-x3<=2, x2-x1<=2, x1-x0<=2 are inconsistent; permanently removing: x4-x3<=2, x2-x1<=2, x1-x0<=2. 
06-18 13:43:44.654: D/gralloc_goldfish(628): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
06-18 13:44:44.684: I/Choreographer(628): Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-18 13:44:47.735: D/dalvikvm(628): GC_CONCURRENT freed 111K, 2% free 11475K/11655K, paused 75ms+95ms, total 251ms
06-18 13:44:57.623: D/chromium(628): Unknown chromium error: -6
06-18 13:46:34.235: D/dalvikvm(628): GC_CONCURRENT freed 276K, 3% free 11644K/11975K, paused 16ms+9ms, total 170ms
06-18 13:46:34.314: D/webviewglue(628): nativeDestroy view: 0x2a1e7108
06-18 13:46:34.314: D/webviewglue(628): nativeDestroy view: 0x2a378640
06-18 13:46:34.314: D/webviewglue(628): nativeDestroy view: 0x2a40dcf8
06-18 13:47:04.044: D/AndroidRuntime(628): Shutting down VM
06-18 13:47:04.044: W/dalvikvm(628): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
06-18 13:47:04.075: E/AndroidRuntime(628): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-18 13:47:04.075: E/AndroidRuntime(628): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.innernet.airway/com.innernet.airway.communication}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
06-18 13:47:04.075: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1541)
06-18 13:47:04.075: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1416)
06-18 13:47:04.075: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
06-18 13:47:04.075: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3312)
06-18 13:47:04.075: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3522)
06-18 13:47:04.075: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3490)
06-18 13:47:04.075: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at com.innernet.airway.comm$1.onClick(comm.java:39)
06-18 13:47:04.075: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
06-18 13:47:04.075: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
06-18 13:47:04.075: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
06-18 13:47:04.075: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-18 13:47:04.075: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-18 13:47:04.075: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
06-18 13:47:04.075: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-18 13:47:04.075: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-18 13:47:04.075: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
06-18 13:47:04.075: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
06-18 13:47:04.075: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-18 13:47:08.784: I/Process(628): Sending signal. PID: 628 SIG: 9
06-18 13:55:51.293: D/dalvikvm(712): GC_CONCURRENT freed 45K, 1% free 11181K/11271K, paused 91ms+8ms, total 155ms
06-18 13:55:51.293: D/dalvikvm(712): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 33ms
06-18 13:55:51.413: D/android.widget.GridLayout(712): vertical constraints: y5-y0>=1038, y1-y0>=128, y2-y1>=128, y4-y3>=128, y5-y4>=128, y5-y0<=1038, y5-y4<=30, y4-y3<=30, y2-y1<=30, y1-y0<=40 are inconsistent; permanently removing: y5-y0<=1038, y5-y4<=30, y4-y3<=30, y2-y1<=30, y1-y0<=40. 
06-18 13:55:51.423: D/android.widget.GridLayout(712): horizontal constraints: x1-x0>=144, x2-x1>=144, x3-x2>=0, x4-x3>=144, x5-x4>=0, x6-x5>=188, x4-x3<=2, x2-x1<=2, x1-x0<=2 are inconsistent; permanently removing: x4-x3<=2, x2-x1<=2, x1-x0<=2. 
06-18 13:55:51.714: D/gralloc_goldfish(712): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
06-18 13:56:29.444: D/chromium(712): Unknown chromium error: -6
06-18 13:56:42.303: D/dalvikvm(712): GC_CONCURRENT freed 109K, 2% free 11539K/11719K, paused 77ms+39ms, total 237ms
06-18 13:56:42.564: D/webviewglue(712): nativeDestroy view: 0x2a0e3578
06-18 13:58:03.575: D/AndroidRuntime(712): Shutting down VM
06-18 13:58:03.575: W/dalvikvm(712): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
06-18 13:58:03.604: E/AndroidRuntime(712): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-18 13:58:03.604: E/AndroidRuntime(712): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.innernet.airway/com.innernet.airway.measure}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-18 13:58:03.604: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
06-18 13:58:03.604: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
06-18 13:58:03.604: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
06-18 13:58:03.604: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
06-18 13:58:03.604: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-18 13:58:03.604: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-18 13:58:03.604: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
06-18 13:58:03.604: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-18 13:58:03.604: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-18 13:58:03.604: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
06-18 13:58:03.604: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
06-18 13:58:03.604: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-18 13:58:03.604: E/AndroidRuntime(712): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-18 13:58:03.604: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at com.innernet.airway.measure.onCreate(measure.java:70)
06-18 13:58:03.604: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
06-18 13:58:03.604: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
06-18 13:58:03.604: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
06-18 13:58:03.604: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  ... 11 more
06-18 14:03:03.764: I/Process(712): Sending signal. PID: 712 SIG: 9
06-18 14:08:10.144: E/Trace(772): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-18 14:08:11.194: D/dalvikvm(772): GC_CONCURRENT freed 49K, 1% free 11181K/11271K, paused 37ms+5ms, total 88ms
06-18 14:08:11.194: D/dalvikvm(772): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 37ms
06-18 14:08:11.304: D/android.widget.GridLayout(772): vertical constraints: y5-y0>=1038, y1-y0>=128, y2-y1>=128, y4-y3>=128, y5-y4>=128, y5-y0<=1038, y5-y4<=30, y4-y3<=30, y2-y1<=30, y1-y0<=40 are inconsistent; permanently removing: y5-y0<=1038, y5-y4<=30, y4-y3<=30, y2-y1<=30, y1-y0<=40. 
06-18 14:08:11.314: D/android.widget.GridLayout(772): horizontal constraints: x1-x0>=144, x2-x1>=144, x3-x2>=0, x4-x3>=144, x5-x4>=0, x6-x5>=188, x4-x3<=2, x2-x1<=2, x1-x0<=2 are inconsistent; permanently removing: x4-x3<=2, x2-x1<=2, x1-x0<=2. 
06-18 14:08:11.583: D/gralloc_goldfish(772): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
06-18 14:08:59.645: D/AndroidRuntime(772): Shutting down VM
06-18 14:08:59.645: W/dalvikvm(772): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
06-18 14:08:59.756: E/AndroidRuntime(772): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-18 14:08:59.756: E/AndroidRuntime(772): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.innernet.airway/com.innernet.airway.measure}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-18 14:08:59.756: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
06-18 14:08:59.756: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
06-18 14:08:59.756: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
06-18 14:08:59.756: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
06-18 14:08:59.756: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-18 14:08:59.756: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-18 14:08:59.756: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
06-18 14:08:59.756: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-18 14:08:59.756: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-18 14:08:59.756: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
06-18 14:08:59.756: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
06-18 14:08:59.756: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-18 14:08:59.756: E/AndroidRuntime(772): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-18 14:08:59.756: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at com.innernet.airway.measure.onCreate(measure.java:74)
06-18 14:08:59.756: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
06-18 14:08:59.756: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
06-18 14:08:59.756: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
06-18 14:08:59.756: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  ... 11 more
06-18 14:08:59.944: D/dalvikvm(772): GC_CONCURRENT freed 87K, 2% free 11560K/11719K, paused 81ms+18ms, total 276ms
06-18 14:10:10.003: E/Trace(819): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-18 14:10:11.164: D/dalvikvm(819): GC_CONCURRENT freed 52K, 1% free 11181K/11271K, paused 97ms+5ms, total 167ms
06-18 14:10:11.164: D/dalvikvm(819): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 16ms
06-18 14:10:11.274: D/android.widget.GridLayout(819): vertical constraints: y5-y0>=1038, y1-y0>=128, y2-y1>=128, y4-y3>=128, y5-y4>=128, y5-y0<=1038, y5-y4<=30, y4-y3<=30, y2-y1<=30, y1-y0<=40 are inconsistent; permanently removing: y5-y0<=1038, y5-y4<=30, y4-y3<=30, y2-y1<=30, y1-y0<=40. 
06-18 14:10:11.284: D/android.widget.GridLayout(819): horizontal constraints: x1-x0>=144, x2-x1>=144, x3-x2>=0, x4-x3>=144, x5-x4>=0, x6-x5>=188, x4-x3<=2, x2-x1<=2, x1-x0<=2 are inconsistent; permanently removing: x4-x3<=2, x2-x1<=2, x1-x0<=2. 
06-18 14:10:11.744: I/Choreographer(819): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-18 14:10:11.764: D/gralloc_goldfish(819): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
06-18 14:10:25.694: D/AndroidRuntime(819): Shutting down VM
06-18 14:10:25.694: W/dalvikvm(819): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
06-18 14:10:25.833: E/AndroidRuntime(819): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-18 14:10:25.833: E/AndroidRuntime(819): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.innernet.airway/com.innernet.airway.measure}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-18 14:10:25.833: E/AndroidRuntime(819):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
06-18 14:10:25.833: E/AndroidRuntime(819):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
06-18 14:10:25.833: E/AndroidRuntime(819):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
06-18 14:10:25.833: E/AndroidRuntime(819):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
06-18 14:10:25.833: E/AndroidRuntime(819):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-18 14:10:25.833: E/AndroidRuntime(819):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-18 14:10:25.833: E/AndroidRuntime(819):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
06-18 14:10:25.833: E/AndroidRuntime(819):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-18 14:10:25.833: E/AndroidRuntime(819):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-18 14:10:25.833: E/AndroidRuntime(819):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
06-18 14:10:25.833: E/AndroidRuntime(819):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
06-18 14:10:25.833: E/AndroidRuntime(819):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-18 14:10:25.833: E/AndroidRuntime(819): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-18 14:10:25.833: E/AndroidRuntime(819):  at com.innernet.airway.measure.onCreate(measure.java:67)
06-18 14:10:25.833: E/AndroidRuntime(819):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
06-18 14:10:25.833: E/AndroidRuntime(819):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
06-18 14:10:25.833: E/AndroidRuntime(819):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
06-18 14:10:25.833: E/AndroidRuntime(819):  ... 11 more
06-18 14:10:26.003: D/dalvikvm(819): GC_CONCURRENT freed 87K, 2% free 11560K/11719K, paused 87ms+4ms, total 255ms
06-18 14:15:25.887: I/Process(819): Sending signal. PID: 819 SIG: 9
06-18 14:17:13.253: E/Trace(868): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-18 14:17:14.543: D/dalvikvm(868): GC_CONCURRENT freed 56K, 1% free 11181K/11271K, paused 89ms+5ms, total 148ms
06-18 14:17:14.543: D/dalvikvm(868): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 20ms
06-18 14:17:14.664: D/android.widget.GridLayout(868): vertical constraints: y5-y0>=1038, y1-y0>=128, y2-y1>=128, y4-y3>=128, y5-y4>=128, y5-y0<=1038, y5-y4<=30, y4-y3<=30, y2-y1<=30, y1-y0<=40 are inconsistent; permanently removing: y5-y0<=1038, y5-y4<=30, y4-y3<=30, y2-y1<=30, y1-y0<=40. 
06-18 14:17:14.664: D/android.widget.GridLayout(868): horizontal constraints: x1-x0>=144, x2-x1>=144, x3-x2>=0, x4-x3>=144, x5-x4>=0, x6-x5>=188, x4-x3<=2, x2-x1<=2, x1-x0<=2 are inconsistent; permanently removing: x4-x3<=2, x2-x1<=2, x1-x0<=2. 
06-18 14:17:14.963: D/gralloc_goldfish(868): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
06-18 14:17:24.444: D/AndroidRuntime(868): Shutting down VM
06-18 14:17:24.444: W/dalvikvm(868): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
06-18 14:17:24.553: E/AndroidRuntime(868): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-18 14:17:24.553: E/AndroidRuntime(868): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.innernet.airway/com.innernet.airway.measure}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-18 14:17:24.553: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
06-18 14:17:24.553: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
06-18 14:17:24.553: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
06-18 14:17:24.553: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
06-18 14:17:24.553: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-18 14:17:24.553: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-18 14:17:24.553: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
06-18 14:17:24.553: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-18 14:17:24.553: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-18 14:17:24.553: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
06-18 14:17:24.553: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
06-18 14:17:24.553: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-18 14:17:24.553: E/AndroidRuntime(868): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-18 14:17:24.553: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at com.innernet.airway.measure.onCreate(measure.java:74)
06-18 14:17:24.553: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
06-18 14:17:24.553: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
06-18 14:17:24.553: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
06-18 14:17:24.553: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  ... 11 more
06-18 14:17:24.694: D/dalvikvm(868): GC_CONCURRENT freed 87K, 2% free 11560K/11719K, paused 76ms+40ms, total 223ms
06-18 14:17:29.084: I/Process(868): Sending signal. PID: 868 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash.

Comment: logout and cancel are not initialized

Answer (score 0):

Raja, the first line of your logcat has the issue and the solution

> > 06-18 13:47:04.075: E/AndroidRuntime(628): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.innernet.airway/com.innernet.airway.communication}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

All you need to do is declare the activity in your manifest. Please google up how to do it. You will get 500 results in .000001 seconds.

Comment: NO I have that file in my file but I was able to see the following error Unhandled event loop exception. So I could able to detect my error.

Comment: Ok this was my new error Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.innernet.airway/com.innernet.airway.measure}: java.lang.NullPointerException